# Add the current menu item CSS class to a custom page type archive in Wordpress menu

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, css, custom-post-type-archives

I've been reading a lot about this but couldn't find a solution.

Basically I'm trying to show a current menu item on a dynamic page that is created by a custom page type archive.
The default menu control doesn't add the current-menu-item CSS class names.
I've found a solution here - http://bloggingsquared.com/blogging-tips/how-to-add-the-current-menu-item-css-class-to-a-custom-link-in-a-wordpress-menu/

Which is like this:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'AddCurrentMenuItemClass',1,2);

function AddCurrentMenuItemClass($classes,$item)
{
    $link = site_url().$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if(strpos($link, $item->url) !== false)
    {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the Home page (which is a custom menu item) is highlighted as well as the page I'm on.
If I change the if statement to:

```
     if ( $link == $item->url )
```

Then in works on that page as but not on sub pages.

Can you please help me sort this out?
I'm working on a client project with a right deadline...

I'm on WP 3.4.2 with a premium WooThemes template: Whitelight

Comment: The home page? You mean the link to the home page also has the `current-menu-item` class as well as the page you are viewing? Is that right?

Comment: @userabuser yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do,

```
  add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'cpt_archive_menu_filter', 10, 3 );
  function cpt_archive_menu_filter( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    foreach ( $items as &$item ) {
    if ( $item->type != 'custom' ) continue;
      if (  get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'your-post-type' && $item->title == 'Title of Link' ) {
        $item->classes []= 'class-name-your-want';
        } 
    }
    return $items;
  }
```

Although the above will work, **Custom Links** get assigned the `current-menu-item` class so this shouldn't be necessary, if I follow you correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe that the theme has a function to recognise the Home custom menu item. The home doesn't highlight when I'm  on a regular page, only on the custom when the code I wrote above is on.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, no classes are being added to the stated menu item.

Answer (score 0):

This works out-of-the-box, thanks for the heavy part of the work to both of you.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', function($items, $menu, $args) {
  foreach ($items as &$item) {
    if (is_single()) {
      if (strpos(site_url().$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $item->url) !== false) {
        $item->classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
      }
    }
  }
  return $items;
}, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. This is what I do:
Change the **YourMenuItem** to your menu name item.

```
/* Add a custom class to a specific menu item */
function my_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( $item->title == "YourMenuItem" ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-page'; 
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This always applies the class, regardless of if the menu item is currently viewed or not.